# How do I select an element by part of its attribute name

Tags: html, dom, selector

**HTML**

```
<div data-a-b-c="...">A</div>
<div data-a-b-d="...">B</div>
<div data-a-c-b="...">C</div>
```

I want to select nodes `A` and `B` by using something like:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[a-b*]")
```

which used to work in Chrome but got broken over time. I only need support for modern browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("*"))
  .filter(element => 
    Array.prototype.slice.call(
      element.attributes
    )
    .find(att => 
      att.localName.match(/data-/)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with selector, looping through the entire scope is rather unlegant.